# How can I use Ingress to comunicate with pod rest endpoint?

Tags: kubernetes, routes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, endpoint

I have a Service TPLM with a pod. This pod is running a REST API with the endpoints /acquire and /release.

In the ingress yaml file I specify that requests to "/tplm" should be redirected to that pod, but I can´t reach the endpoints (/acquire and /release). I only reach the pod.

Ingress yaml file:

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: iesd-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: isos.iesd.pt
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /tplm
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: lockmanager-service # Needs to match the service name
                port:
                  number: 9002
```

Comment: Any purpose of adding following in ingress annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /  this will redirect the traffic to root

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!